# How to open NetCDF4-CF files from SMAP in xarray

Tags: xarray

I've downloaded a list of netCDF4-CF files from SMAP (Following [this guide](https://nsidc.org/data/user-resources/help-center/programmatic-data-access-guide) in jupyter notebook) to get daily soil moisture data over 2020 in South Sudan. The result is a series of .nc files that I would like to open with xarray's `open_mfdataset()`. However, to check the validity of the files, I tried opening one using `open_dataset()` and found no dimensions. [image: Preview of xarray dataset from one of the netCDF files]

I know the files aren't corrupted, because a quick `gdalinfo` on one of them returns plenty of information, including subdatasets for lat, long, and soil_moisture[image: subset of results from gdalinfo]
and I can open the file in QGIS, although it includes some layers that need to be hidden (lat and long)[image: QGIS preview of one of the netCDF files]

So my question is: **How can I open this file properly in xarray?**

My parameters to the api are as follows:

- short_name=SPL3SMP_E
- version=005
- temporal=2020-01-01 -> 2020-12-31
- polygon=[LONG STRING OF POLYGON COORDINATES FOR SOUTH SUDAN]
- format=NetCDF4-CF
- projection=GEOGRAPHIC
- Coverage=latitude,longitude,soil_moisture